# Service wont start under Windows 7: FAILED 1053

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-services

I wrote a C++ service that functions perfectly under Windows XP but fails to start in Windows 7. SC CREATE returns success, however, SC START returns FAILED 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. From what I understand this is caused by timeout, but I receive the error immediately.

Is this a problem with my service code or some setting in 7?

Does Windows 7 send service control requests differently then XP?
If so, how would I go about catching the start request?

Please let me know if you need to see the code as well as any other information that will help solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at  the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793731/starting-a-windows-service-fails-with-error-1053)

Comment: The only way to get it immediately is to quickly return from the service control handler but not switch the service control state.

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem by installing MSVCR100D.dll into system32. No need to even change my code.

Comment: That's the debug build of the CRT; you don't want to run that in a production environment (and it is not redistributable).  Rebuild your project in release configuration.