# How to efficiently write code and debug windows service project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-services

How to efficiently write code and debug windows service project in visual studio? Visual Studio gives

> Cannot start service from the command
>   line or a debugger.  A Windows Service
>   must first be installed (using
>   installutil.exe) and then started with
>   the ServerExplorer, Windows Services
>   Administrative tool or the NET START
>   command.

when I want to debug my code. It seems to me that it is inefficient to test the code. One has to install a service, start it, attach the debugger, test it, and then uninstall it.

Thanks,
Gil.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128164/easiest-way-to-develop-debug-a-windows-service-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196531/how-to-debug-net-windows-service-onstart-method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398826/vs2008-on-win7-64-bit-debugging-a-windows-service, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first comment mentioned there are many other items out there...but I wanted to put a little light on this as well.

1. You can use a post build event to manage the process of installing after build etc, so that you don't have any effort needed there.
2. You can use `Debugger.Break()` to be able to start debugging right away.  This way you are not playing the "Attach" game.

These will at least get you going, and help reduce the "pain" you experience.

Comment: Can you expand upons the Debugger.Break suggestion?  I'm not aware of this and play the Attach game... :(

Comment: Sure, in your init code put Debugger.Break().  That will trigger a popup for you to start debugging using Visual Studio!