# Window Service Getting Hanged on Starting

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a Windows service which is logging user activities of the Windows system and makes a REST API request to the server for preserving  data..

But I am facing the issue that when the system starts it causes the user System to hang.

Window Application log Reports:

```
Version=1
EventType=ServiceHang
EventTime=130095268907958116
ReportType=3
Consent=1
UploadTime=130123814084883007
ReportIdentifier=6fe19abe-9ce8-11e2-afdf-00218508c07c
Response.BucketId=6956ff7a549827f0fa19859393538633
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=-743991677
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Service Name
Sig[0].Value=DMAService
Sig[1].Name=Image Name
Sig[1].Value=Com.Altair.DMA.DMAService.exe"
Sig[2].Name=Image Version
Sig[2].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[3].Name=Service Type
Sig[3].Value=10
Sig[4].Name=Start Type
Sig[4].Value=2
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.2.9200.2.0.0.768.101
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Altair Engineering Inc\DMAService\Com.Altair.DMA.DMAService.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\374a0cc6603f58864831897ef723bd4a\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\a7811936e59aaee26b1d9d467174d6d4\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv759bfb78#\1f3dbc5b0a874bf49a4559e71274f8ba\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Management\cb1bedf1f9e8972aa76ad73f725b964b\System.Management.ni.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\05cc6faa6704d01e78700561b22937e3\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\e1ec8b9a6d4f9af9d6065c4187fb1b5f\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\wminet_utils.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wmiutils.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\0247de206c1c48ac4f8b55df16468405\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rasapi32.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rasman.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[46]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[47]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
State[1].Key=Headless.2ndLevelConsentNeeded
State[1].Value=1
File[0].CabName=WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Path=WER756D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Flags=327682
File[0].Type=5
File[0].Original.Path=C:\Windows\Temp\WER756D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[1].CabName=memory.hdmp
File[1].Path=WER761A.tmp.hdmp
File[1].Flags=2162688
File[1].Type=3
File[1].Original.Path=C:\Windows\Temp\WER761A.tmp.hdmp
File[2].CabName=minidump.mdmp
File[2].Path=WERAEA7.tmp.mdmp
File[2].Flags=2359298
File[2].Type=2
File[2].Original.Path=C:\Windows\Temp\WERAEA7.tmp.mdmp
FriendlyEventName=Service Hang Report
ConsentKey=ServiceHang
AppName=DMAService
AppPath="C:\Program Files\Altair Engineering Inc\DMAService\Com.Altair.DMA.DMAService.exe"
ReportDescription=Service DMA Service hung on starting
```

But I am not able to decipher what is cause making service to hang at warm boot (the service is running in elevated permission).

Can I debug my service when the system starts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug the .NET Windows Service OnStart method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196531/how-to-debug-the-net-windows-service-onstart-method)

Comment: Off topic, is this you server's MAC address: _00-21-85-08-C0-7C_? :)

Comment: This is a client system mac address.