# How to make application stop and run debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have .NET service and I need to debug it.

I want it to stop when it reaches some place in code and start the debugger. 
Can anyone provide some code sample?

UPDATE

Simply adding

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

does not work for Windows service.

Comment: I've simply added debugger launches to my win services with it successfully working.

Comment: 2 jlafay. Well may be I ve got some permission issue. I am running the service on Windows 2003 server, where I have Visual Studio installed and it does not start the debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`Debugger.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx), as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c/126016#126016) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `Debugger.Launch();` to the place in your code where you want to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following code to the place where you want to stop service.
2. Run Service.
3. Attach debugger
4. Add f to watch, change it value to false
5. Continue debugging

   bool f=true;
   while(f)
   {//<- Add breakpoint here

   }

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps for that:

1) Stop & uninstall the running service
2) Rename or remove the release version of the service
2) Create a Debug build of the service
3) Install this debug build of service
4) Start the service
5) Open the service solution from Visual studio
6) Select Tools->Attach process
7) In the process list you will see the running service, Attach it
8) Set breakpoints wherever required

Comment: This does not address my question.