# C# - WCF Duplex => Fire an event when a client disconnect

Tags: c#, wcf, events, callback

I'm trying to let my service knows when one of the clients is disconnected.

I'm using wsDualHttpBinding.

Currently, I'm tried to use this event :

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler((sender, e) => ClientIsDisconnected(sender, e, currentCallbackChannel));
```

But this event is never fired...

Please help me to know how it'd be done !

Edit :

Thanks to anderhil, I finally replaced wsDualHttpBinding by netTcpBinding (with the appropriate configuration described here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx#Step1).

With netTcpBinding, the Closed event fires without any problem... Still don't know why but it works.

Comment: so you haven't received the event even once? How do you test it? 
Where do you use your code?(in what operation) Why do you need duplex?

Comment: Nope I haven't received it yet. I test it by quitting one of my client WinForm. I attach the EventHandler when one of my client is connecting to the service, just after that I have registered the current CallbackChannel to a Channel List. I need duplex to let each client know when an other client is disconnected.

Comment: I edited my Question, with more code.

Comment: Add some button to WinForm, and when button is clicked take the client channel and call .Close() or .Abort() method and then try to test it by clicking the button. Also uncomment the Faulted event - these two events always should go together in such cases.

Comment: Also, it is interesting why these events are not called, but overall, this method of handling events doesn't cover cases when your client machine will be powered off, or client router will turn off, or smth like this, cause client should send some die message to let service know about client is turning off. So in your case i'd do some timer which "asks" all clients whether they are alive.

Comment: If I understood, I shouldn't .close() my service connection immediately after that I received what I wanted ? And when I will quit the client application, the connection will be closed itself ? I think I misunderstood something...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31200/discussion-between-anderhil-and-oliboy50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is likely becuase of WsDualHttpBinding. In case you have this binding, two connections are created, from client to service and from service to client.

When the application is deployed over the internet it can create some issues with supporting such applications, you need to be sure that people are not behind the firewall or NAT or etc that can prevent your service to connect back to client.

I still don't know why it doesn't work on local machine when testing, but i will try to resolve it and update the answer.

As you told me more details in our chat, from the nature of your application it's better to use NetTcpBinding. In this case it's easier to understand what is happening cause one connection is created, and you will receive the notifications in case of gracefull close or abort of client.

As i told you before, anyway it's better to create some heartbeat mechanism to have things more reliable in case of unexpected computer or router shutdown.

Also, you can find this good cheat sheet on how to select communication between parties that involve WCF:

[image: wcf binding cheat sheet]

Answer (score 1):

The `Closed` event should occur on a graceful disconnect; is that what's happening?
To detect the pure socket disconnect, listen for the [`Faulted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.faulted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(FaultedHandler);
```

Comment: In fact, i tried both... How can i be sure if the event is fired ? I put a Console.WriteLine("blabla") in the function ClientIsDisconnected. But i'm not even sure if i can see it in the Service Output...

Comment: To debug the service, attach to it; good instructions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710758/55487)

Comment: Hum... it seems that my service is already attached.. Can you give me an example about how i should use this Event, maybe i do it wrong.

Comment: The EventHandler should be attached before or after that I register the `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IService1Callback>()` into my channel list ?