# TcpListener.AcceptSocket() fails in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-services, tcplistener

I have an instance of the following code that executes correctly in Debug or as a standalone Windows application:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4554);
tcpListener.Start();

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        using (Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket())
        {
            // Code here is reached in Debug or as a Console Application
            // but not as a Windows Service
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        // This is never reached
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This is never reached
    }
    finally
    {
        // This is never reached in the Windows Service
    }
}
```

However, when I install it as a Windows Service, it crashes on `tcpListener.AcceptSocket()`, and logs the following to the Event Viewer:

> An unhandled exception ('System.Net.Sockets.SocketException') occurred in MyService.exe [768]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: The operation attempted is not supported.

Even trying to catch the exception I am unable to log anything more. Stepping through code in Debug accomplishes nothing because the code successfully blocks the application and waits for a client connection.

Is there a way to implement this for a Windows Service?

Comment: It's likely that the `Start` that is what is throwing the `SocketException`. Since it isn't in your try, your catch and finally aren't being hit. Move your `Start` into your try, and examine the ErrorCode property of your `SocketException` in your catch statement. That will give you a better idea of what is wrong. Then check the ErrorCode against [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what the exact problem is.

Comment: Make yourself familiar with how to debug services. It's possible.

Comment: @vcsjones I tried that with the same result. I also added logging just before and after `tcpListener.AcceptSocket()`, it successfully logs before the call but not after.

Comment: Thank you @usr. I did as you advised and discovered my service logic was re-instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr)'s advice (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710758/1195620)) led me to a bug in the code. The ServiceBase class contained the following:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _worker = new Thread(ExecuteService);
    _worker.Start();
}

private void ExecuteService()
{
    for (;;)
    {
         if (_stop.WaitOne(1000))
        {
            new TcpServer().StartTcpServer();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The correct implementation was to remove the `for` loop, which was re-instantiating the listener. Here is the final code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _worker = new Thread(ExecuteService);
    _worker.Start();
}

private static void ExecuteService()
{
    new TcpServer().StartTcpServer();
}
```