# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET project (windows forms) created in .net 3.5.

I added Error log code to this project and I deployed it in VS2010 with .NET 4.0 platform.

It successfully builds and creates the installer, but when I install this msi installer it shows the error "error:1001 ->Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and the installation gets rolled back.

If any one knows about this error please help me.

Comment: Run your installer from the debugger and see where it raises the exception.

Answer (score 4):

One of the resons could be that Custom Actions data is missing. Make sure the variables/properties/data you are accessing in the installer's code(ProjectInstaller.cs) file is there in the custom actions data in Install section.

1. Click SetupProject
2. on top of solution explorer click Custom Actions
3. select Install->Primary output from project
4. Select properties.
5. check CustomActionData.(the variables used in the installer code file should be there in the property).

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the installer is actually copying all the dlls and other files to the installation directory.

Comment: Then try @ChrisF's suggestion.

Comment: no i hav services in my project.when i go with debugger its giving the error."you cant install it from the debugger/cmd."

Comment: So this means you have installer class. Your null object is in that class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c