# Debugger.Launch() not working

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services

**I have window background service to read Message queue using NServiceBus.**

I want to debug this windowservice to trace the flow so have added `Debugger.Launch()` inside Service class when i run service its launching service in debuggermode.

But

Now i want to keep debugger at `RequestDataMessageHandler.cs` class which initiated when a message reaches queue.

I want to debug this class so kept `Debugger.Launch()` inside this class. But debugger in not launching. Handler class reads message from queue.

What will be the cause?

Comment: Have you tried a logging framework, like NLog or Log4net? They help alot when it comes to debugging servicers, and have a multiple targets to write to. IE, file, event log, database, UDP, TCP/Ip.

Comment: On StackOverflow: [Easier way to start debugging a windows service in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c)

Comment: Well, it probably *did* work since you didn't get an exception.  Problem is that it is displaying the just-in-time debugger selection dialog on the session 0 desktop.  The one that the user can never get to.  There's no workaround for it, you have to attach a debugger yourself from your own desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that debugger is already attached, in case of debugger is already attached `Debugger.Launch()` does not work. Try using `Debugger.Break()`, it will break if debugger is already attached or not.