# debugging window service

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services

I want to debug window service. What should i write in main() to enable debugging in window service. I am developing window service using C#.

```
#if(DEBUG)
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
      this.OnStart(null);
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
 #else
      ServiceBase.Run(this);
 #endif
```

i wrote above code segment but on line (this

Comment: Your question isn't complete.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:
In your service's `OnStart` method add the call to `Debugger.Break()` at the top:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    #if DEBUG
        Debugger.Break();
    #endif

    // ... the actual code
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I personally use this method to debug a Windows service:

```
static void Main() {

    if (!Environment.UserInteractive) {
        // We are not in debug mode, startup as service

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyServer() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    } else {
        // We are in debug mode, startup as application

        MyServer service = new MyServer();
        service.StartService();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

And create a new method in your `MyServer` class that will use the `OnStart` event:

```
public void StartService() {
    this.OnStart(new string[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#if DEBUG
while (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

It waits until you attach a debugger, *then* breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug it without installing , In **Program.cs** class add below lines and make a breakpoint in function , then click **F5**

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

         Service1 myService = new Service1();
         myService.CallMethodNeedDebuging();
    }
```