# does not debug windows service in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, debugging, windows-services

I follow this [question in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995565/debugging-window-service) the code that I put in the designer shared sub main was:

```
  #If DEBUG Then
    Dim servicio As New CopyFileWorkManagerService
    servicio.OnStart(Nothing)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
 #Else
      Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase               
      ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1} 
      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)                   
  #End If
```

everything debugs well until this line: AddHandler oTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.oTimer_Elapsed

```
Private Sub New()
     InitializeComponent()

    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()

    oTimer = New Timer(My.Settings.Intervalo)
    Debugger.Break()
    AddHandler oTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.oTimer_Elapsed
End Sub
```

the method     Private Sub oTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

does not debug!!

what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to debug a piece of code in service then attach that service with the debugger.

Comment: You are never starting the timer, so it never elapses.