# Running Windows Service Application without installing it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

Whem I'm writing a Windows Service and just hit F5 I get the error message that I have to install it using `installutil.exe` and then run it.
In practice this means everytime I change a line of code:

1. compile
2. switch to Developer Command Prompt
3. remove old version
4. install new version
5. start service

That is very inconvenient. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually put the bulk of the service implementation into a class library, and then create two "front-ends" for running it - one a service project, the other a console or windows forms application. I use the console/forms application for debugging.

However, you should be aware of the differences in the environment between the debug experience and when running as a genuine service - e.g. you can accidentally end up dependent on running in a session with an interactive user, or (for winforms) where a message pump is running.

Comment: I agree. Having all the heavy code as a class library also makes it possible to do automatic testing. Services are notoriously hard to debug, so make the actual "service" as small as possible. Sorry for being late to the party :)

Answer (score 22):

The best way in my opinion is to use `Debug` directive. Below is an example for the same.

```
#if(!DEBUG)
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
         // Calling MyService Constructor 
            new MyService() 
    };
     ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
  MyService serviceCall = new MyService();
  serviceCall.YourMethodContainingLogic();
#endif
```

Hit `F5`  And set a `Breakpoint` on your `YourMethodContainingLogic` Method to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

You can write this code in program.cs

```c
//if not in Debug
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
{ 
   new MyService() 
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

//if debug mode
MyService service = new MyService();
service.OnDebug();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

in MyService class

```c
public void OnDebug()
{
   OnStart(null);
}
```

Comment: Would be great to have a bit of explanation on what the code is doing.

Comment: If you want to debug installer service without installing then you can use the code attached then you will be able to debug service .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run Windows Service as say another console or WinForms application. It needs to be started by Windows itself.

If you don't have infrastructure ready to use as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests (which is what I recommend as well) you can install the service from the debug location. So you use `installutil` once and point it to executable located in `/bin/debug`. Then you start a service from `services.msc` and use `Visual Studio > Debug > Attach to Process` menu and attach to the Windows service.

You can also consider using `Thread.Sleep(10000)` as the first line in the `OnStart` call, or `Debugger.Break()` to help you out to be able to attach before the service executes any work. Don't forget to remove those before the release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.UserInteractive` variable. Details of implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126163/2393504)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way I use to debug Windows service applications without installing them, starting via Windows Service Control Manager, attaching to debuggers, etc. The following is in VB but hopefully you get the idea.

In this example, TestService's main class is named `svcTest.vb`.

Within `Shared Sub Main()` inside `svcTest.Designer.vb`, the default code looks something like this:

```
Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New svcTest}
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
```

Comment everything out within Main() and add the following 2 lines of code.

```
Dim objSvc As New svcTest()
objSvc.OnStart(Nothing)
```

Now just set a breakpoint where you want to start debugging, hit F11 to step into the code, and then proceed as normal as if you were working with a standard desktop application. When you're finished debugging, simply reverse the changes made within Main().

This was done using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on Windows Server 2012 R2.