# Debugging a Windows Service - Prevent Cannot Start Service

Tags: c#

Trying to deubg a windows service (removed the need to install, code, install, code, etc..), thought I found the solution

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[]args) 
    {
        ClientService service = new ClientService();

        if (args.Length > 0) 
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(service.Main, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Console.WriteLine("running...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        else 
        {
#if (!DEBUG)
            ServiceBase[]ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new MyService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
# else
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
        }
# endif
    }
}
```

However I'm still getting the error:

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A windows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

[image]

Any Ideas what I need to change to avoid the prompt?

Comment: Pass a command line parameter in the project's debug properties tab. Any parameter will do. Don't just copy-paste code without understanding it.

Comment: What did the google results say when you googled that error message text?

Comment: According to the error message, a Windows Service must be installed using `installutil.exe` instead of run from the command line or debugger.  Did you try doing that?

Comment: Did you add an install project?

Comment: @David this code is one of the many instances where instead of through `ServiceBase.Run()`, the service class is actually started through user code, to debug a service without installing it. This code does that if `args.Length > 0`. It's like the first Google hit for "C# debug windows service without installing". There's absolutely no need to install a Windows Service to debug its logic.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Interesting, I've never seen this approach used.  Makes sense.  I guess I've just never encountered this problem, as my service code has always been independently runnable/testable without needing to run the service host itself.  (The last time I encountered this error message was long ago when maintaining a legacy system where the procedure was to have the services installed and running on dev machines anyway.)

Comment: @David oh, absolutely, if you actually need this you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have copied the code from [Running Windows Service Application without installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21722847), but it was broken by design and you altered it incorrectly.

The thought behind it, is that you have a `ServiceBase`-inheriting class containing a public method that performs the actual service logic:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    public void DoTheServiceLogic()
    {
        // Does its thing
    }

    public override void OnStart(...)
    {
        DoTheServiceLogic();
    }
}
```

Then in your application, you can start it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService() 
        };

        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

This provides an executable application that can be installed as a Windows Service.

But you don't want to have to install your service and then attach Visual Studio to debug it; that's a horribly inefficient workflow.

So what the code you found attempts to do, as many approaches found online do, is to start the application with a certain command line flag, say `/debug`, which then calls the public method on the service logic - **without actually running it as a Windows Service**.

That can be implemented like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "/debug")
        {
            // Run as a Console Application
            new MyService().DoTheServiceLogic();
        }
        else
        {
            // Run as a Windows Service
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyService() 
            };

            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can instruct Visual Studio to pass the `/debug` flag when debugging your application, as explained in [MSDN: How to: Set Start Options for Application Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx).

That's slightly better, but still a bad approach. You should extract the service logic altogether, and write unit tests to be able to test your logic without having to run it inside an application, let alone a Windows Service.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

Create a partial class with the same name as tour service:

```
 public partial class AlertEngineService
    {
        public void Run(string[] args)
        {

            OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program alert engine service");
            Console.Read();
            OnStop();
        }
    }
}
```

and call this command on debug:

```
var servicesToRun = new ClientService ();
servicesToRun.Run(args);
```

you can also change the service configuration to run as console (in the properties section).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Start with changing your code a bit :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if DEBUG // If you are currently in debug mode
    ClientService service = new ClientService (); // create your service's instance
    service.Start(args); // start this service
    Console.ReadLine(); // wait for user input ( enter key )
#else // else you're in release mode
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun; // start service normally
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new MyService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
}
```

In your service add this method :

```
public void Start(string[] args)
{
    OnStart(args);
}
```

Now all you need to change is in properties change application type from `Windows Application` to `Console Application`.

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        new ClientService().Start();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); //Ensure your service keeps running             
        #else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #endif
    }
}
```

In ClientService.cs

```
public void Start()
{
    OnStart(null);
}
```