# The correct way to debug a windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have installed the windows service using `installutil service1.exe`

When I click `Debug`, I get the error message `Windows Service Start Failure: Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger...`. Hence I tried Attach to Process -> Service1 from the Debug menu. However, when I click on `Attach to Process`, it automatically enters `Debug mode and does not respond to any of my break points`.

What step am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-start-debugging-a-windows-service-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

The following changes allows you to debug windows services just like any other Console application.

Add this class to your project:

```
public static class WindowsServiceHelper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    public static bool RunAsConsoleIfRequested<T>() where T : ServiceBase, new()
    {
        if (!Environment.CommandLine.Contains("-console"))
            return false;

        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Where(name => name != "-console").ToArray();

        AllocConsole();

        var service = new T();
        var onstart = service.GetType().GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        onstart.Invoke(service, new object[] {args});

        Console.WriteLine("Your service named '" + service.GetType().FullName + "' is up and running.\r\nPress 'ENTER' to stop it.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        var onstop = service.GetType().GetMethod("OnStop", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        onstop.Invoke(service, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then add `-console` to the debug options for the windows service project.

Finally add this to `Main` in `Program.cs`:

```
 // just include this check, "Service1" is the name of your service class.
    if (WindowsServiceHelper.RunAsConsoleIfRequested<Service1>())
        return;
```

From my blog post [An easier way to debug windows services](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/an-easier-way-to-debug-windows-services)

Comment: I added the method. And updated my Debug configuration with "-console". However, when I try to Debug it by pressing F5, I still get the same error

Comment: You added it to the wrong textbox. Check the blog post for a screen shot.