# How to debug the OnStart() method, using breakpoints for windows services using C#?

Tags: c#

I am working on a Windows service, and I would like to run the debugger and make breakpoints for the OnStart() method.

I have already add the line `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` in the OnStart method and breakpoints work perfectly for other methods like OnStop or the handler of the timer I set.

I tried to make breakpoints in my Onstart method and it seems like they are ignored, but the code I wrote works fine. To avoid this problem I wrote a log file for each breakpoints but I really want to make breakpoints as same as other situation.

This is my OnStart method (example):

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);  // here I make breakpoint for test but it doesn't work
        Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        Timer.Interval = 20000; //number in milisecinds  
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Personally I debug windows services by adding an #if DEBUG block that contains a public method PublicOnStart that calls OnStart, and another #if DEBUG block in the Program.cs with a static void main that makes a new service instance and calls PublicOnStart(), then the whole lot works just by pressing play in vs

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-debug-a-windows-service for some alternative methods

Comment: (The community wiki answer originally from Jason Miller is a version of what I mentioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [TopShelf library](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20for%20this%20is,the%20application%20as%20a%20service.) , it does what i needs : debug application like a console and release it as a service.