# Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-debugging, installutil

I am developing a windows service project but I face different problems.

1.

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.

I already install the service by using installutil but after I install the service, it can start in mmc.

2. I use this code before:

```
public void onDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}
```

```
#if DEBUG
            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            myService.onDebug();
            Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Push_Message_Service()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
```

Because I want to debug in visual studio but I sometimes need to start the service in Service mmc. I don't want to build in Release folder when I need to start the service.
So everyone please help me to fix the problems, thank you you guys!

Comment: Try with only the #else part even in debug mode. To me it seems the #if part does nothing at all.

Comment: *"Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger"* what command line do you use?
Service is essentially an EXE, which you can run in a regular manner in VS. Or using Service Control in windows. If you debug, you don't need to run it as service.

Comment: Reply to PMF - If I use debug mode, it will show the error that I mention.  The #if debug will run onDebug void that is in Service1 and It sleep forever. The perpose of doing this is it can run onStart void directly without running the code: Service.Run(ServicesToRun); so that can run the service code without triggering the error (because ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); will trigger the error: Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger).

Comment: Reply to TS - Because it is a service class, it will run as service and it will trigger the error

Comment: if you want to reply to someone you must include @[user].. It seems that you have some technical issue, If you debug, debug uninstalled service, Or installed, which is running and you can attach to it. If you already installed the service, you can stop/start and replace exe/dll with debug version, whatever.

Comment: Is this your answer? https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=931873

Comment: It doesn't have too much efficiency to do that, I don't want to attach debugger to my services

Answer (score 0):

I created a windows service project in visual studio 2022 and it popped the error message when i debugged the windows service.

[image]

It looks like you are not able to  debug from code in visual studio without installing and starting your service.
Were you encountering the same error message ? If so,please make sure you have installed your windows service by installutil and start your service.
Please refer to [How to start services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-start-services)

As you mentioned above, you have used `#if DEBUG` to debug windows service and it worked fine.

Or you can start the service through the Windows Service Control Manager and then attaching the debugger to the thread.
For more information, please follow  [To debug a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications#to-debug-a-service)

Here is a similar ticket:

[Easier way to debug a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-debug-a-windows-service)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I already install the service by installutil but I don't use the #if debug thing, it will not work. I need sometimes need to debug in visual studio and I also need to install service and run in mmc, if I use #if debug it cannot run the service in mmc

Comment: `#if debug` does prevent the service from running in the MMC.Based on your particular needs,i suggest you build the service in both Debug/Relase mode.`Debug` for debuging in visual studio and `Release` for MMC.

Comment: But I think it is not much productivity for changing to Release when I need to start the service in MMC.

Comment: After checking the [Debug Windows Service App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications#to-debug-a-service)again,it notes "To debug a service, you must start the service and then attach a debugger to the process in which it is running". I am afraid that you have to attach debugger to your services.